# Accessing Arduino Yun from Internet

Tags: arduino-yun

I am trying to access my Arduino Yun from the internet, and it's not quite working. I have correctly port forwarded the port 5555 from the router to the Yun (verified I am able to access my many other NAT'd resources).

I can access the Yun from my internal network.

In the Arduino sketch I have this (among many other things). Mainly taken from example sketches.

```
#include <Bridge.h>
#include <HttpClient.h>
#include <YunServer.h>
#include <YunClient.h>

YunServer server;

void setup {
   // Listen for incoming connections on port 5555
   server.noListenOnLocalhost();
   server.begin();
}
```

Is `server.noListenOnLocalhost();` the right one to use to access from the outside world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not familiar with the Yun, but the first thing that stands out is the missing

```
Bridge.begin();
```

line apparently needed to initialize the Bridge library that you use.

And you do have something like

```
YunClient client = server.accept();
```

and "more" in the main loop (or a function where applicable) of your code, right ?

And yes, `noListenOnLocalhost()` is the correct function for serving external clients.

Comment: Yes, I have `Bridge.begin();` and `YunClient client = server.accept();` is there within the `loop`. I'm able to access everything internally, just not externally.

Comment: So your answer helped me validate that what I am doing is correct. I'll mark it as solved. What ended up happening is that my router didn't save the NAT for port 5555. So I re-did that, and it's good. Thanks again for verifying that `noListenOnLocalhost()` is correct for external hits!

Comment: @Pat Glad to have... ahem... "helped" :-)

Comment: You did! I wasn't sure if `noListenOnLocalhost()` was correct, and the documentation on `noListenOnLocalhost` vs `listenOnLocalhost` wasn't overly clear (I think they both say the exact same thing).

Comment: The doc is "correct", but indeed not very explicit regarding internal VS external. And I must admit that when I first saw the function name I found it rather suspect.